# How could I update Chinese language (like 我) to mysql

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
@main.route('/edit-about',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def edit_about():
    form = EditAboutForm();
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.about_me = form.about_me.data;
        try:
            db.session.add(current_user);
        flash('Your about has been updated');
    form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me;
    return render_template('edit_about.html',form=form)
```

The error is like this.

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x88\x91' for column 'about_me' at row 1") 'UPDATE users SET    about_me=%s, about_me_html=%s WHERE users.id = %s' ('\xe6\x88\x91', 
>    '
>
> \xe6\x88\x91
>
> ', 1L)

Is SQLite support Chinese.But MySQL doesn't?

Comment: have you tried `English`?

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @learner Engilsh can be update.

Comment: @BidhanA  I'm using flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

It's charset problem on my MySQL.So I create new databases default charset is utf8.And now update Chinese data to MySQL was succeed.

The way to create utf8 charset database.
[MySQL Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html)

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Or you can use `db.create_db` to create database and tables.